# Appending to a linked list, code doesn't always work

Tags: c, linked-list, append

```
void AppendList (Node *new_node, Node *head) {
    Node *walker = head;
    while (walker->next != NULL)
        walker = walker->next;
    walker->next = new_node;
}
```

When appending to a linked list, our professor wrote this code in the slides, and he said that this won't always work. Can you please explain to me why?

Answer (score 1):

You did not make sure that `new_node->next == NULL`, at least not in this code.

Answer (score 0):

In the case when `head == NULL`, you will dereference a NULL pointer here `while (walker->next != NULL)`, probably crashing the program.

You will need to add an if statement that will check for head being NULL.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a condition before while loop for checking walker is NULL or NOT.

```
if(walker==NULL)
{
  head = new_node;
  return;
}
```